# Unused argument for creating a Matrix function

Tags: r

I am trying to turn a matrix command into a function in r but I am getting an unused argument error whenever I try to use it.

```
matrix <- function(a,b) {
  matrix(a,ncol=b)}

matrix(10, 10)

Error in matrix(a, ncol = b) : unused argument (ncol = b)
```

I tried to google solutions to this problem but none seem to relate to my specific problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `matrix` is aalready a function.  You may change the function name.  i.e. when you define a function with `matrix`, the inner one is also trying to do a recursive call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better not to name object names with an already available function as this causes confusion and it may not call the correct function.  Inside the function, it is supposed to be calling the `base::matrix`, but instead, it calls the function defined with `matrix` as a recursive call.  We may need

```
matrix <- function(a,b) {
   base::matrix(a,ncol=b)
 }
```

-testing

```
> matrix(10, 10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
```

NOTE: As mentioned above, it would be better to name the function as a different name i.e.

```
m1 <- function(a, b) {
     matrix(a, ncol = b)
}
```

-testing

```
rm(matrix)
> m1(10, 10)
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10
```